# Inserting individual characters of a string into an array

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm new to Python and I'm attempting to place each individual character of a string into an individual element of an array.

```
string= 'Hello'
array= []

length_of_string= len(string)-1

for i in range (length_of_string):
    array.append(string(i))

print(array)
```

However when I run this code an error occurs as shown below.

```
   array.append(string(i))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The `append` function works fine when I append to an array using strings or numbers normally but in this instance it does not work.

What do I have to do to get

```
['H','e','l','l','o']
```

Comment: Anything wrong with `list('Hello')` ?

Comment: `string(i)` is not correct – it is 'not callable' because it is not a function. (If you use the correct form `string[i]`, you still get a suprising result because of that (surprising!) earlier `-1`.)

Comment: Use `string[i]` - as @usr2564301 points out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean `string[i]` if you wan't the `i`th element of `string` (not `string(i)` -- python isn't matlab). However, it's much faster just to do

```
list(string)  # ['H','e','l','l','o']
```